# Mapping thru Objects - Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I want to ask how to create a mapper for objects in the way that typescript recognizes the returned type

Example:

```js
type ExampleObject = {
  text: string; // this object can contain any property of any type
  number: number;
};

const object: ExampleObject = {
  text: 'asd',
  number: 1
};

const object2 = generator(object); // the "object" can be any object

// expected type for this case
type ExpectedObject = {
  text: () => string;
  number: () => number;
};

// expected value
object2 ===
{
  text: () => 'asd',
  number: () => 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `generator` function would look something like this:

```
function generator<
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(obj: T) : { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, () => v])
  ) as any
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQPICMBWEDGwUAvFAN4BQUUwEcwAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmA3FShcArkiwQ2TEWIkCAvgIr4A9l1ZRluAo1iIU6bHkIlyg2vSYByBMwAmlgDSDp4yVACMFBRQoAzYVyEHKpQPBBcEgjAymwAPAAqUHS0XLbMUABKBDG2saycvA5QAQDWXMoA7lwAfNUAFJo4TPEAlFBMZADaANJQ3FAlECDKvlDxALpMdW3E1WM943Lk1IJsEMDCbFxQhtoAdL5sykgwXOwcEMx1u4R74eeXDbgte0gIYHV1nSVFAG7jMzm3yK0xIc3+LTaNigCC4IC8PhUaiIjW0ACYTGEImwojEnkZgC0BEA)